# Rewriting sentences with nouns or verbs

Tags: grammar

How do I rewrite these sentences with the form in parentheses?

> 1. I bought the new car because the salesperson **impressed** me with his offer. *(impressive)*
> 2. My teacher gave us a very **motivational** talk about doing our best. *(motivate)*
> 3. I gave out my account information because I was fooled by a thief's **impersonation** of my bank. *(impersonate)*

Comment: This appears to be an exercise designed to help you practice shifting between related nouns and verbs. What do you _think_ the answers should be? Where _exactly_ are you confused?

Comment: @Tyler James Young Yes, but I don't know how to form the sentence properly .

Comment: Please write your attempt so that we know what to explain.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. I bought the new car because the salesperson **impressed** me with his offer. *(impressive)*
>
>    - I bought the new car because of the *salesperson’s **impressive*** offer.
> 2. My teacher gave us a very **motivational** talk about doing our best. *(motivate)*
>
>    - My teacher ***motivated*** us *a lot by giving a* talk about doing our best.
> 3. I gave out my account information because I was fooled by a thief's **impersonation** of [a representative of] my bank. *(impersonate)*
>
>    - I gave out my account information because I was fooled by a thief **impersonating** [a representative of] my bank.

In 1., you must change from the verb “impressed” (past tense of “impress”) to the adjective “impressive”. When dealing with adjectives, it can be helpful to determine which other word the adjective will modify. In this case it’s the *offer* that’s impressive, so I’ve placed the adjective “impressive” directly before “offer” to make that association clear. I’ve also shifted indication of possession (of “offer”) from “his” to “’s”.

In 2., the task is to use the verb “motivate” instead of the adjective “motivational”. Since “gave” is past tense, I replaced it with the past tense “motivated”. The subject of the verb is still “my teacher” and the object is still “us”, but now the teacher is motivating us *directly.* To restore the indication of how the teacher motivates us, I reintroduce the verb “give” in the phrase “by giving a talk”.

in 3., you’re asked to replace the noun “impersonation” with the verb “impersonate”. This one can be done quickly by simply removing the possessive from thief and using the present participle form of “impersonate”. What this means is that we’re no longer describing the impersonation itself as “a thief’s” (that is, belonging to a thief). We are now describing the *action* of “impersonate” as something the thief is doing. Since impersonation takes place between two people, I’ve also changed the sentence to refer to “a representative of my bank”. Strictly speaking, it’s not possible for a person to impersonate a bank.